# I want to break from loop when input is not given

Tags: c

I have a code written in c:

```
int num1,num2;
while(1)
{
   scanf("%d",&num1);
   scanf("%d",&num2);
}
```

I want to break out of this loop when input is not given when the program runs.

Comment: `scanf()` *does* return a value, though you wouldn't know it from the kind of code you find online.

Comment: have you trie using `break;`?

Comment: What do you mean by 'when input is not given'?  Do you mean you want it to time out if nothing is read within 30 seconds, say?  Or if the input line is blank?  Or something else?  Note that `scanf()` et al don't care in the slightest about newlines or blanks (at least, not when the only formats are `%d`) — it just skips them.

Comment: You should enlighten us a little bit more. What do you mean by : _I want to break out of this loop when input is not given when the program runs_

Comment: Please give some examples of what your use case will be, in what situations we should be breaking out of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You asked, and that is much, much more than I normally see.

Try the following:

```
int num1, num2;

while (1) {

    if (scanf(" %d %d", &num1, &num2) != 2) {

        /* End of input (Ctrl+D)? */
        if (feof(stdin))
            break;

        /* No, just invalid input. */
        fprintf(stderr, "That was not two integer numbers. I'm out.\n");
        break;
    }

    printf("You supplied %d and %d.\n", num1, num2);
}
```

You see, the scanf family of functions returns the number of successful conversions. Above, if `scanf()` does not read and convert two integers, we check if it failed because it encountered end of input (if it did, then `feof(stdin)` is true). Otherwise, it must have failed because the input was something else. We cannot retry, because the unparseable input is still unread -- the next try would just fail the same way. (There are ways to *consume* the bad input, but I'd just read the input line-by-line, and try and parse (or reject) each line instead.)

I see so much code that never checks the return value of any of the scanf family of functions, and so many questions on the behaviour caused by it (incorrect input causing endless loops, maybe out of memory situations, buffer overruns), that it sometimes feels futile to even read a question related to any scanf() function. But, you asked. (And, the other you, reading this question and answer but not being the OP, are *interested* in the matter.) That is good. That means, perhaps someone actually cares about writing *robust* programs that don't get into a hissy panic whenever the input diverges just a bit from the expected. I want robust programs.